# Laravel 9 Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel

Good Day,

Im Creating routes for forget password. after i put it in sanctum authentication it wont work. but but when i put it outside sanctum authentication by then it will work.

Need help. New to Laravel

Thanks

Below Screenshots [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CE2ST.png)

Tried removing the middleware for forgot password. still doesnt work.

Comment: Is the forgot  password only accessible when user is not logged in ?

Comment: @xenooooo yes only if admin user is loggedin. because the forgot password is for normal user only